# Fetching records using join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Below is sample data and a query which returns the result.

```
create table tab1 (grp_id number, mid number);
create table tab2 (grp_id number, mid number);

insert into tab1 values(1, 5);
insert into tab1 values(1, 6);
insert into tab1 values(1, 7);
insert into tab1 values(1, 8);
insert into tab1 values(2, 9);
insert into tab1 values(2, 10);

insert into tab2 values(1, 5);
insert into tab2 values(1, 6);
-----------------------------------------
select *
  from tab1 t1, tab2 t2
 where t1.mid = t2.mid(+)
   and t1.grp_id in (select grp_id from tab2)
  ;
```

```
| GRP_ID | MID | GRP_ID |    MID |
|--------|-----|--------|--------|
|      1 |   5 |      1 |      5 |
|      1 |   6 |      1 |      6 |
|      1 |   7 | (null) | (null) |
|      1 |   8 | (null) | (null) |
```

Can I have above result without using In or Exists clause.. just by using join left right or case. Please do consider that this is sample data

Please help thanks.

Comment: With the sample data provided, it looks like simply doing an outer join using `mid` and `grp_id` as the join columns would work.  But I suspect that's not what you want.  You may want to provide more complex test data that illustrates why that approach will not work.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) What query returns what result? What is output in terms of any input, using words? A guess, in terms of code: tab1 left joined with tab2. Read the manual: it says *how OUTER JOINs work* & (+) goes on the table that gets NULLs & "You cannot compare a column with a subquery in the WHERE clause of any outer join" & *don't use (+)*.

Comment: Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a correlated query where the columns from the outer query goes in as a parameter to the inner query.
this is the only solution:

```
select t1.grp_id,t1.mid ,(select t2.grp_id from Tab2 t2 where 
t1.grp_id=t2.grp_id and t1.mid=t2.mid ),
(select t2.mid from Tab2  t2 where t1.mid=t2.mid and t1.grp_id=t2.grp_id)
from tab1 t1 where t1.grp_id=1
;
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9113e/2

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the results by using a `left join` directly

```
select t1.grp_id as grp_id_1,t1.mid as mid_1,
       t2.grp_id as grp_id_2,t2.mid as mid_2
  from tab1 t1 
  left join tab2 t2 on t1.grp_id=t2.grp_id and t1.mid=t2.mid
 where t1.grp_id=1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9113e/6)</kbd>

Comment: thanks... but that shared data is sample data... grp_id could be any value and there is large no of data...

Comment: @Raghvendra welcome, no matter how the magnitude od the data.